# Sumologic sending alerts to SLACK

Tags: slack, sumologic

I tried to send alerts from `Sumologic` to Slack. But when I test the connection, it always failed and return 400 `http` code. I used the connection type as `Webhook`

When test the connection, it should pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using WebHook and testing the connection, you must use a valid payload. If you don't provide a valid payload, the connection test will not succeed.

You can use the connection type as SLACK over WebHook. Still, you are using a webhook URL.

This link shows how to integrate Sumologic with Slack.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qEz8dcp9SgI